# Как реализовать второе меню?

Tags: java, android

[image: ФОТО]

Есть нижняя панель меню, хочу сделать второе меню и там  при выборе "Текст1" будет ссылаться на  "Главную", т.е чтобы нижняя панель тоже двигалась. Не хочу использовать Drawable Navigation, так как нужно использовать активити, а у меня все во фрагментах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается это довольно просто. Пункт меню, это фрагмент, который будет содержать список с пунктами которые соответствуют нижнему меню. Это может быть либо список RecyclerView или просто linearLayout с какими-то textView например. Дальше когда вы нажимаете на элемент списка в фрагменте, вы используя интерфейс между этим фрагментом и активностью-контейнером. В метод интерфейса вы будете передавать id пункта нижнего меню который должен быть выбран. И по итогу в методе интерфейса который используется в активности вы производите программный выбор пункта нижнего меню:

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.main);
```

Как передавать данные из фрагмента в родительскую активности? Делаем интерфейс:

```
public interface OnDataPass {
    public void onDataPass(Int data);
}
```

дальше в этом фрагменте подключаем интерфейс:

```
OnDataPass dataPasser;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    dataPasser = (OnDataPass) context;
}
```

передача данных при выборе элемента списка менюшки в фрагменте:

```
dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
```

В активности делаем implement `OnDataPass`:

```
@Override
public void onDataPass(Int data) {
    Log.d("LOG","hello " + data);
}
```

[Вот как](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977370/9363441) подключаем фрагмент к интерфейсу и активность. Дальше в методе `onDataPass` в активности делаем через switch например:

```
@Override
public void onDataPass(Int data) {
switch(data){
   case (1):
     bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.main);
   }
   ....
}
```